# Inserting multiple values to mysql from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am adding values to tables using this command.
This code helps to add multiple rows to the table and also we can delete a row by selecting the unwanted rows.

But now I have to insert those added rows from html table to mysql php table after posting it.

How to insert the added values from table to mysql table.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https:///abn/main.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".add-row").click(function(){
                var name = $("#name").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var price = $("#price").val();
                var markup = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + email + "</td><td>" + price + "</td></tr>";
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
            });

            // Find and remove selected table rows
            $(".delete-row").click(function(){
                $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
                    if($(this).is(":checked")){
                        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        });    
    </script>

<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Product Description</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Total Price</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>              
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="delete-row">Delete Row</button>
<input type="button" class="add-row btn btn-success" value="Add Row">
```

Comment: You need to `POST` or `GET` your data from your javascript into PHP, from PHP you will then update your db.

Comment: Use Ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ? The idea : you send data from your front to a php file then send back a response. So when you add a row, send the data in a php file using ajax, in the php file insert the new data, this way you can insert / delete data without reloading the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively to the comments above, you may wrap your table inside a `<form>` tag, add a [Save] input that acts as a command button, so you minimise the writings to only what is validated by the user, and finally, use jQuery `.serialize()` method to supply data to an XHR method, such as jQuery.ajax, or jQuery.post

Part of your HTML layout, you will have added 3 input fields per table row, `txtName_<pk>`, `txtPrice_<pk>` and `txtEmail_<pk>` for instance, that will be automatically sent as data by .serialize().

The good thing about suffixing them with the primary key (pk) for each row, is that you can have your PHP form processor to extract this primary key, to issue the proper SQL command : `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or even `REPLACE`. 
It may also be used to report back to the user that such or such row couldn't be inserted, specifying it by its unique PK...
Good luck!

**EDIT** 
Example:

**in HTML**

```
<form id="frmTable">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="txtName_10244" value="John Doe" />John Doe</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="txtEmail_10244" value="john.doe@state.country.earth" />john.doe@state.country.earth</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="txtPrice_10244" value="314.15" />$314.15</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<input id="cmdSave" type="submit" />

</form>
```

**in JavaScript**

```
$("#cmdSave").click(function() {
    $.post("processor.php", $("#frmTable").serialize())
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("Your table was saved.");
    });

});

//  You may exploit here the data (JSON) that was returned by processor.php
```

**in PHP (processor.php)**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$data = array('success' => false, 'error' => null);
$errors = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {

    if (preg_match("/^txtName_(\d+)$/", $key, $bits)) {
        // all right, we've got a row, so let's send its data to the function that saves it.

        $ans = saveRow(
            $primaryKey = $bits[1],
            array(
                'name' => $val,
                'email' => $_POST["txtEmail_" . $primaryKey],
                'price' => $_POST["txtPrice_" . $primaryKey]
            )
        );
        if (!$ans) $errors []= "Couldn't save row #" . $bits[1];

    } 

}

if(empty($errors))
    $data['success'] = true;
else
    $data['error'] = implode('<br />', $errors);

exit(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Comment: I am using <form> tag bug I haven't included here

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: @udhay, did my example help?